# Clang invalid -Wfor-loop-analysis

Tags: c++, clang, warnings

Clang (version 17.0.6) complains:
`warning: variable 'i' used in loop condition not modified in loop body [-Wfor-loop-analysis]`

on this code:

```cpp
int i = 0;
auto add = [&]
    {
        cout << i;
        i++;
    };
for (; i != 3; )
    add();
```

Because clang can't realize that `i` is actually changed.

If you are wondering, the reason I don't modify i++ in the for loop statement is because this `add` function is reused later.

Should I just disable this warning?

Comment: As a kluge, you can placate the warning by `volatile int i = 0;`

Comment: `for (; i != 3; i += 0)` seems to solve the warning too. Making `i` `volatile` is probably overkill.

Comment: Another options to let your lambda accept an int reference instead of capturing the int by reference. `auto add = [](int& i) { i++; }` and use `add(i)` Example : https://godbolt.org/z/oc6d7sY6T. In any case I think this is more of compiler bug than anything else. For now you could disable the warning locally in your code, or fix the code, to be honest your solution is not all that maintainable (invisible side effects)

Comment: using volatile triggers `-Wdeprecated-volatile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No warnings with `while (i != 3)`.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jczcee3ss)

Comment: I agree that `while` is semantically better anyways